# Swift class function returning empty after for-in loop

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, for-in-loop

I am trying to build a simple Library-Shelf-Book model in Swift and I am running into a strange issue. Within the following Library Class, my func total book count is returning 0 every time. I know its probably something simple I'm overlooking but any help would be awesome. Here is my library class:

```
class Library
{

var allShelves:[Shelf]=[]
var allBooksCount = 0

var description: String{
    return "This Library has \(allShelves.count) Shelves with \(allBooksCount) books"
}

func addNewShelf(newShelf: Shelf){
    var newShelf = Shelf()
    self.allShelves.append(newShelf)
    println("There are \(allShelves.count) SHELVES in this library")

}

func totalBookCount() -> Int{
    for currentShelf in allShelves{
        allBooksCount = currentShelf.numberOfBooks
    }
    return allBooksCount
}


}
```

Here is my Shelf class:

```
class Shelf
{

var allBooksOnShelf:[Book] = []
var numberOfBooks = 0

init(){
    self.allBooksOnShelf = []
}

var description: String{
    return "This Shelf has \(allBooksOnShelf.count) Books"
}

func addNewBook(newBookToAddToShelf: Book){
    let newBook = Book(bookName: newBookToAddToShelf.bookName)
    self.allBooksOnShelf += [newBookToAddToShelf]
    numberOfBooks = allBooksOnShelf.count
    println("new book called \(newBook.bookName)")

}
}
```

Here are my tests:

```
let newLibrary = Library()
//println(newLibrary.description)


let libraryShelf1 = Shelf()
newLibrary.addNewShelf(libraryShelf1)

let libraryShelf2 = Shelf()
newLibrary.addNewShelf(libraryShelf2)

libraryShelf1.addNewBook(Book(bookName: "Game Of Thrones"))
libraryShelf1.addNewBook(Book(bookName: "Hunger Games"))
libraryShelf1.addNewBook(Book(bookName: "Return of the Jedi"))

println("this Shelf has \(libraryShelf1.allBooksOnShelf.count) books")

newLibrary.totalBookCount()

println(newLibrary.description)
```

newLibrary.totalBookCount() always returns 0.

Comment: Use the debugger to trace through and watch the variable values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 errors:

**Error 1**

```
func addNewShelf(newShelf: Shelf){
    var newShelf = Shelf()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    self.allShelves.append(newShelf)
    println("There are \(allShelves.count) SHELVES in this library")        
}
```

Here you are redefining `newShelf` parameter as a local variable, losing what is passed in. The correct implementation is:

```
func addNewShelf(newShelf: Shelf){
    self.allShelves.append(newShelf)
    println("There are \(allShelves.count) SHELVES in this library")        
}
```

**Error 2**

Here:

```
func totalBookCount() -> Int{
    for currentShelf in allShelves{
        allBooksCount = currentShelf.numberOfBooks
    }
    return allBooksCount
}
```

at each iteration you reinitialize the `allBooksCount` property, so in the end what the func returns is the count for the last shelf in the loop. You should add instead (using the `+=` operator) - moreover resetting the counter at beginning would also be a good idea (otherwise if you call the function multiple times you have incorrect results):

```
func totalBookCount() -> Int{
    self.allBooksCount = 0
    for currentShelf in allShelves{
        allBooksCount += currentShelf.numberOfBooks
    }
    return allBooksCount
}
```

Comment: wow! thanks so much! i knew it was something small, this worked perfectly thanks!!

Comment: Glad it worked :) Don't forget to mark the answer as the solution